# how to append \ and "" to string literally in Lua

Tags: lua, append

I am trying to concat 2 strings and also append some characters to them. For example

```
local currdir
local node
local arg = (currdir..node)


function(arg)
etc....
```

but "arg" needs to have a "\" at the end of it, and be surrounded by doublequotes. So literally passed to function like "arg\". Does anyone know how to do this? cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about

```
arg = ([["%s\"]]):format(arg:gsub('\\+$',''))
```

This also removes any already existing trailing backslashes. For jigsawing pathnames together, you can also take a look at table.concat, and have the different pieces in a table.

Comment: cheers concat actually worked better for me, made things a little less complicated. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

I think `arg='"'..curdir..node..'\\"'` should work nicely, e.g.:

```
> curdir='c:\\path\\to\\files\\'
> print (curdir)
c:\path\to\files\
> node='xyz'
> print (node)
xyz
> arg='"'..curdir..node..'\\"'
> print (arg)
"c:\path\to\files\xyz\"
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to use single-quote strings, as then you don't have to escape the double quotes.

```
arg = ' something \\ '
yourfunc(arg)
```

Comment: you still have to escape the \